# Python: remove lots of items from a list

Tags: python

I am in the final stretch of a project I have been working on.  Everything is running smoothly but I have a bottleneck that I am having trouble working around.

I have a list of tuples.  The list ranges in length from say 40,000 - 1,000,000 records.  Now I have a dictionary where each and every (value, key) is a tuple in the list.

So, I might have

```
myList = [(20000, 11), (16000, 4), (14000, 9)...]
myDict = {11:20000, 9:14000, ...}
```

I want to remove each (v, k) tuple from the list.

Currently I am doing:

```
for k, v in myDict.iteritems():
    myList.remove((v, k))
```

Removing 838 tuples from the list containing 20,000 tuples takes anywhere from 3 - 4 seconds.  I will most likely be removing more like 10,000 tuples from a list of 1,000,000 so I need this to be faster.

Is there a better way to do this?

I can provide code used to test, plus pickled data from the actual application if needed.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You'll have to measure, but I can imagine this to be more performant:

```
myList = filter(lambda x: myDict.get(x[1], None) != x[0], myList)
```

because the lookup happens in the dict, which is more suited for this kind of thing. Note, though, that this will create a new list before removing the old one; so there's a memory tradeoff. If that's an issue, rethinking your container type as jkp suggest might be in order.

**Edit**: Be careful, though, if `None` is actually in your list -- you'd have to use a different "placeholder."

Comment: Wow.  This brought my test time from 3.2 seconds to 0.025... I think we may have a winner - at least until Alex Martelli chimes in :)

Comment: I could live with being second to him :-)

Comment: @sberry2A: If you're measuring 25ms, the real wall time might even be smaller than that -- it could be your OS's timer resolution "rounding" it up to 25ms.  Try taking the average of 1000 runs, for instance.

Comment: Ran the test 2000 times.  Average time is 0.024.  SUPER!

Comment: Darn, I was busy yesterday -- ah well, I'll post my answer anyway, even though it's late;-).

Answer (score 9):

To remove about 10,000 tuples from a list of about 1,000,000, if the values are hashable, the fastest approach should be:

```
totoss = set((v,k) for (k,v) in myDict.iteritems())
myList[:] = [x for x in myList if x not in totoss]
```

The preparation of the set is a small one-time cost, wich saves doing tuple unpacking and repacking, or tuple indexing, a lot of times. Assignign to `myList[:]` instead of assigning to `myList` is also semantically important (in case there are any other references to `myList` around, it's not enough to rebind just the name -- you really want to rebind the *contents*!-).

I don't have your test-data around to do the time measurement myself, alas!, but, let me know how it plays our on your test data!

If the values are not hashable (e.g. they're sub-lists, for example), fastest is probably:

```
sentinel = object()
myList[:] = [x for x in myList if myDict.get(x[0], sentinel) != x[1]]
```

or maybe (shouldn't make a big difference either way, but I suspect the previous one is better -- indexing is cheaper than unpacking and repacking):

```
sentinel = object()
myList[:] = [(a,b) for (a,b) in myList if myDict.get(a, sentinel) != b]
```

In these two variants the sentinel idiom is used to ward against values of `None` (which is not a problem for the preferred set-based approach -- if values are hashable!) as it's going to be way cheaper than `if a not in myDict or myDict[a] != b` (which requires two indexings into myDict).

Comment: I think we were all looking forward to seeing your answer.  (Note: one minor typo in your first code line ('i'))

Comment: tx for the typo spotting, fixing it now

Answer (score 5):

Every time you call `myList.remove`, Python has to scan over the entire list to search for that item and remove it.  In the worst case scenario, every item you look for would be at the end of the list each time.

Have you tried doing the "inverse" operation of:

```
newMyList = [(v,k) for (v,k) in myList if not k in myDict]
```

But I'm really not sure how well that would scale, either, since you would be making a copy of the original list -- could potentially be a lot of memory usage there.

Probably the best alternative here is to wait for Alex Martelli to post some mind-blowingly intuitive, simple, and efficient approach.

Comment: This is much much faster than my original code.  However, it is about 3 - 4 times slower than balpha's and Nick Lewis' answers.

Answer (score 2):

The problem looks to me to be the fact you are using a `list` as the container you are trying to remove from, and it is a totally unordered type.  So to find each item in the list is a linear operation ([O(n)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)), it has to iterate over the whole list until it finds a match.

If you could swap the `list` for some other container (`set`?) which uses a `hash()` of each item to order them, then each match could be performed much quicker.

The following code shows how you could do this using a combination of ideas offered by myself and Nick on this thread:

```
list_set = set(original_list)
dict_set = set(zip(original_dict.values(), original_dict.keys()))
difference_set = list(list_set - dict_set)
final_list = []
for item in original_list:
    if item in difference_set:
        final_list.append(item)
```

Comment: Right you are, however I need them to be ordered.  At first I was using a dictionary to store the items in myList as v:k for each (k, v) in myList above.  But because I need them to be ordered I was having to sort the k, v pairs of the dictionary every time I added, changed data.

Comment: OK, if you take the answer provided at by Nick Lewis, then once you have the set of items to keep, you can do the following: iterate over the original list and query the set for membership of each item: if the item is in the set, append it to your final list.  You will end up with an ordered list of the items you want.

Answer (score 2):

```
[(i, j) for i, j in myList if myDict.get(j) != i]
```

Comment: This is the same as balpha's but using a list comprehension instead of filter().

Comment: This should be the same as Mark Rushakoff's, too.

Comment: It's not the same as balpha's or not the same as Mark Rushakoff's? This differs from balpha's in using a list comprehension, as noted, and from Mark Rushakoff's in using "if myDict.get(j) != i" instead of "if not k in myDict". The latter could be different if the key is present but does not map to the same value. Is that the difference you are highlighting?

Comment: what are you trying to prove? that since essential algorithm is traversing a list and checking whether a corresponding value in dictionary all code is the same? because if that's your definition **all** answers on this page are the same!

Comment: I'm not proving anything. I'm also not sure what you are upset about.¶

I think that the set operations are a distinctly different solution than using list comprehensions/filter. I think that removing from lists is different from building a new list. I think it's interesting that "[using in] runs almost twice as fast as using [dict].get(key) because the in operator is faster to execute than a method call." [Python Essential Reference, p.197]¶

There's lots of interesting possibilities in building algorithms in python, some similar and some not.¶

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
myListSet = set(myList)
myDictSet = set(zip(myDict.values(), myDict.keys()))
myList = list(myListSet - myDictSet)
```

This will convert `myList` to a set, will swap the keys/values in `myDict` and put them into a set, and will then find the difference, turn it back into a list, and assign it back to myList. :)

Comment: The times here are very, very close to the ones obtained with balpha's suggestion.  They are +/- 4 milliseconds.  Is one potentially better for larger lists?

Comment: balpha's probably consumes less memory.

Answer (score 0):

```
[i for i in myList if i not in list(zip(myDict.values(), myDict.keys()))]
```

Comment: Did you try this? My reading of your code is that you are doing a linear search for a tuple in a list -- so this is O(n^2) for the whole operation. Every single up-voted solution so far is going to have better performance than this.

Comment: This also evaluates the expression on the right for every item -- going through the `dict` every time.

Answer (score 0):

A list containing a million 2-tuples is not large on most machines running Python. However if you absolutely must do the removal in situ, here is a clean way of doing it properly:

```
def filter_by_dict(my_list, my_dict):
    sentinel = object()
    for i in xrange(len(my_list) - 1, -1, -1):
        key = my_list[i][1]
        if my_dict.get(key, sentinel) is not sentinel:
            del my_list[i]
```

**Update** Actually each del costs O(n) shuffling the list pointers down using C's memmove(), so if there are d dels, it's `O(n*d)` not `O(n**2)`. Note that (1) the OP suggests that d approx == `0.01 * n` and (2) the `O(n*d)` effort is copying one pointer to somewhere else in memory ... so this method could in fact be somewhat faster than a quick glance would indicate. Benchmarks, anyone?

What are you going to do with the list **after** you have removed the items that are in the dict? Is it possible to piggy-back the dict-filtering onto the next step?

Comment: f you're going to do that, you may as well generate the list of keys to delete and do them in reverse order. It seems a bit more idiomatic to me.

delete_me = [i for i, v in enumerate(my_list) if v not in my_dict]; for i in reversed(delete_me): del my_list[i];

Also, Beazley claims that the in-operator is faster then the dict.get-method, FWIW.

Comment: Argh. 

delete_me = [i for i, v in enumerate(my_list) if v[1] not in my_dict];

Comment: (1) If doing it in three steps (including building a temporary list and reversing it) is "idiomatic" then "idiomatic" is bad. (2) using dict.get has the same semantics as the OP's use of list.remove: both k & v must match between list and dict. The OP has not indicated otherwise. (3) In any case you meant "v[1] in my dict" not "v[1] not in dict" -- the dict contains the ones to be deleted. Very premature optibeazation ;-)

Comment: There is a point of view that "xrange(len(my_list) - 1, -1, -1)" is less desirable than "reversed(xrange(len(my_list)))". I know I have been downvoted for suggesting that the range/xrange() with step -1 was idiomatic.